# Make jQuery FIlter Persist after Ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a jQuery selector on document ready to hide an element based on the html text of a descendant element - it works but when there is an Ajax refresh the element is shown again, how can I make it persist after refresh, my code is:

```
 $(".fl-theme-builder-archive-events-tutoring .tribe-filter-bar-c-filter__toggle-label").filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() === "Age Range";
}).closest('.tribe-filter-bar-c-filter').hide();
```

I have identified `tribeAjaxSuccess` as a possible Ajax callback after refresh and tried the code below:

```
   $(document).on('tribeAjaxSuccess', function () {
        // Your code to persist after the Ajax refresh here
        $(".fl-theme-builder-archive-events-tutoring .tribe-filter-bar-c-filter__toggle-label").filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() === "Age Range";
        }).closest('.tribe-filter-bar-c-filter').hide();
    });
```

But it still shows hidden element on refresh

Comment: You could save the state of the element in local or session storage. Why does AJAX reload the page? AJAX is specifically used to not have to reload the page, when changing content within it.

Comment: Ajax reloads due to it being a filter checkbox which refreshes the results but not the page, I'll edit the original question

Comment: How do u trigger Ajax refresh? Do you make a call to server? If you have a button click event that cause of the refresh, you can add your hiding logic here.

Comment: Ajax trigger for refresh is The Events Calendar Filter Bar Plugin - looking though the code I assume `tribeAjaxSuccess` is the callback after the refresh

Comment: *"looking though the code I assume"* - you didn't write the code? that hook on `tribeAjaxSucess` doesn't do anything but hiding things. we are quite unsure with the definition of your *"refresh."*

Comment: My definition of refresh on this page - is that it is a checkbox filtering plugin that when you select a checkbox it changes the results without fully reloading the page in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct callback `afterSetup.tribeEvents` and using the `.on()` method persistently hides the element

```
$(document).on('afterSetup.tribeEvents', function () {
    // Your code to persist after the Ajax refresh here
    $(".fl-theme-builder-archive-events-tutoring .tribe-filter-bar-c-filter__toggle-label").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === "Age Range";
    }).closest('.tribe-filter-bar-c-filter').hide();

});
```